# How can I solve "TypeError at /post/new/" in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

While trying to create a new form in Django vesrsion 2.2. I ran into this error

> TypeError at /post/new/ join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'tuple'.

I have really tried solving the issue but I can't solve it.

These are the steps have taken..

1. I add a new URLConf for post_new at the app level(blog folder)

   ```
   # blog/urls.py
   from django.urls import path
   from . import views
   urlpatterns = [
       path('post/new/', views.BlogCreateView.as_view(), name='post_new'),
   ]
   ```
2. Then, create the view by importing a generic class called CreateView and then
   subclass it to create a new view called BlogCreateView.

   ```
   # blog/views.py
   from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
   from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
   from . models import Post

   class BlogCreateView(CreateView):
       model = Post
       template_name = 'post_new.html'
       fields = '__all__'
   ```

And the last step is I create the template, which we will call post_new.html.

```
<!-- templates/post_new.html -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>New post</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Edited to add the full traceback

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/new/
>
> Django Version: 2.2 Python Version: 3.7.3 Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles',  'blog']
>   Installed Middleware:
>   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Traceback:
>
> File "C:\Users\user
>   pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ntpath.py" in join
>     89.         for p in map(os.fspath, paths):
>
> During handling of the above exception (expected str, bytes or
>   os.PathLike object, not tuple), another exception occurred:
>
> File "C:\Users\user
>   pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File "C:\Users\user
>   pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     145.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "C:\Users\user
>   pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     143.                 response = response.render()
>
> File "C:\Users\user
>   pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py"
>   in render
>     106.             self.content = self.rendered_content
>
> File "C:\Users\user
>   pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py"
>   in rendered_content
>     81.         template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
>
> File "C:\Users\user
>   pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py"
>   in resolve_template
>     63.             return select_template(template, using=self.using)
>
> File "C:\Users\user
>   pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py"
>   in select_template
>     42.                 return engine.get_template(template_name)
>
> File "C:\Users\user
>   pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py"
>   in get_template
>     34.             return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
>
> File "C:\Users\user
>   pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py"
>   in get_template
>     143.         template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
>
> File "C:\Users\user
>   pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py"
>   in find_template
>     125.                 template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)
>
> File "C:\Users\user
>   pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py"
>   in get_template
>     18.         for origin in self.get_template_sources(template_name):
>
> File "C:\Users\user
>   pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\filesystem.py"
>   in get_template_sources
>     36.                 name = safe_join(template_dir, template_name)
>
> File "C:\Users\user
>   pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils_os.py"
>   in safe_join
>     32.     final_path = abspath(join(base, *paths))
>
> File "C:\Users\user
>   pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ntpath.py" in join
>     115.         genericpath._check_arg_types('join', path, *paths)
>
> File "C:\Users\user
>   pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\genericpath.py" in
>   _check_arg_types
>     149.                             (funcname, s.**class**.**name**)) from None
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /post/new/ Exception Value: join()
>   argument must be str or bytes, not 'tuple'

Am using python3.7 with django2.2

Comment: Can you share the *full* traceback?

Comment: I will @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Did you by any change wrote `template_name = 'post_new.html',` (so with a comma at the end)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I don't think so but let me check

Comment: no you should remove tailing comma's. This looks like the most logical explanation, that you made something a tuple.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes I did. Thanks I have removed it and its now working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the error, you wrote something like:

```
# blog/views.py
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from . models import Post

class BlogCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_new.html',  # a trailing comma
    fields = '__all__'
```

As a result the `template_name` is *not* a string, but a singleton tuple containing a string. You should *remove* the tailing comma.